# Range of the solutions for $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x+16} = 3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

The given equation is

$$ \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x+16} = 3$$

What is the range of the solution?

Comment: Note $x$ cannot be negative, so $\sqrt{x+16}\ge4$.

Comment: How do you usually solve equations that have square roots in them? Try that and see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly existence of $\sqrt x\implies x\geq 0$ for $x\in \Bbb R$.Thus, $\sqrt {x+16}$ is atleast $4\implies \sqrt x+\sqrt {x+16}\geq 4$ for $x\in \Bbb R\implies$ no real solution for $\sqrt x+\sqrt {x+16}=3$

Answer (score 3):

Try this.  Be aware $x\ge 0$ or we are dead on the spot.  We begin with this.

$$\sqrt{x + 16} = 3 -\sqrt{x}$$
Squaring gives
$$x + 16 = 9 - 6\sqrt{x} + x. $$
Now cancel to get 
$$6\sqrt{x} = -7. $$
This does not look so good.  I think it's devoid of real solutions.

Comment: There aren't any solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Take square of both sides and get 
$$
2x+16+2\sqrt{x(x+16)}=9
$$
We thus get 
$$
\sqrt{x(x+16)}=-x-\frac{7}{2}. 
$$
Take square of both sides and get
$$
x(x+16)=x^2+7x+\frac{49}{4}. 
$$
This is a quadratic equation in $x$, so the rest is easy.

Comment: But then you have to plug the solutions you find into the original equation to see if they are real or were introduced by the squaring.

Comment: You are right. I noticed David Mitra's comment above.